# Can TeamCity listen to tfs builds and trigger my automation tests

Tags: tfs, teamcity

We are using team foundation server for checking in the code and building the project.
Now, we would like to add to TeamCity to trigger our automation suite as soon as a build is pushed to tfs.

Question:
Can TeamCity listen to TFS build information and call my automation scripts to execute? (I checked every where, it says teamcity performs build, I want tfs to perform a build and do post actions)

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We are using TFS 2013

Answer (score 0):

VSTS/TFS 2015 and later has the feature that integrating with your favorite services by notifying them when events happen in your project. It provides a way to send a JSON representation of an event to any service. More information: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/services/webhooks

You need check on TeamCity side to see whether it can receive the JSON representation of an event from TFS.

Comment: If you use TFS 2013, then you need to use TFS API to create server-side event handler to listen to BuildCompletionNotificationEvent, then check on TeamCity side to see whether it can get the notification from TFS.